# Fast way to search lines of Tmemo

Tags: performance, delphi, tmemo

I have a TMemo on a form which allows users to enter a list of items. People can enter many items here. When they click Save the contents of the TMemo is checked and then added to the database.

I have a second list in a TStringList which I loop over and check to see if any of it's items are contained in the TMemo.

In a nut shell it looks like this

```
....
//slItems = TStringList
//mItems = TMemo
for i := slItems.Count -1 downto 0 do
begin
  if mItems.Lines.IndexOf(slItems[i]) = -1 then
    slItems[i].Delete;
end;
----
```

So stringlist looped, check to see if it exists in memo, if not delete from list.

However, with 200+ items this is starting to slow down a lot, and with 1000 it gets real bad.

Whats the fastest way to search a TMemo?

Comment: @Marco There is no TStringList here. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Another aside. If you were using a rich edit then you could use EM_FINDTEXT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read all of `TMemo` into a local `TStringList` and work from that. Every time you're accessing `TMemo.Lines` you're relying on Windows messaging to talk to the windows-provided multi line text box. Anything but efficient!

```
....
//slItems = TStringList
//mItems = TMemo
//L = TStringList
L.Text := mItems.Text; // edited per David's suggestion.
L.Sorted := True; // per Uwe Raabe's suggestion.
for i := slItems.Count -1 downto 0 do
begin
  if L.IndexOf(slItems[i]) = -1 then
    slItems[i].Delete;
end;
----
```

Comment: `StringList.Text := Memo.Text` is the quick way to do this.

Comment: @David, I've always used the `Assign()`; I've just looked what `TStrings.Assign(TStrings)` does and it's a horror story... Thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: As the order of the items in L is of no relevance, add `L.Sort` before the loop and you should go much faster.

Comment: @Uwe, `L.Sorted := True` makes it fast, `L.Sort` doesn't.

Comment: Made it CW, because out of 3 lines of code added to the OP's code, two came from peer comments.

Comment: It's faster when sorted because binary search can be used, but the string list can only take advantage of this when it *knows* that it is ordered. That's why it's not enough just to sort the list, you have to tell the list that it has been sorted too.

Comment: Yes +1 for sort, it speeds things up as it uses binary search.

Comment: I don't know why calling sort does not set Sorted to true. It should.

Comment: @Runner, it shouldn't. When the list is `Sorted := True`, if you add something, it's placed in sorted order; If the list is not sorted, is added as the last element of the list.

Comment: @David, @Cosmin: There's nothing horrible about `TStrings.Assign`.  Instead of just copying text, it makes sure other settings are identical, and that string/object association is preserved.  Assigning `.Text` won't do any of those things.

Comment: @mason for a memo there's nothing but the strings so what you want is a simple WM_GETTEXT as I suggested.